# Spring Boot integration test against real postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker-compose, integration-testing

I have been looking at this problem now for hours and I know it's something silly.

My `Spring Boot` integration test can't find my `Postgres` table (relation) while the REST API works fine.

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "data_source" does not exist`

The DB is `Postgres` in `Docker` container (not using in mem container).

Here relevant code.

Any help will be much appreciated !

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.16</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

test/resources/application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
# parses java variables in camel case to data base naming convention with underscores
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class TrainingDataServiceIT {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    DataSourceRepository dataSourceRepository;

    @Test
    public void myTest() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(post("/get-ds")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content()
                        .contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    }
```

EDIT to add my entity (columns emitted):

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "data_source")
public class DataSourceEntity {
```

EDIT

```
postgres=# \dn
  List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner
--------+----------
 public | postgres
(1 row)
```

Edit:

```
version: '3'


services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:10.15-alpine
        container_name: postgres
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        volumes:
            - ./postgres/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
```

Comment: @MarkB Sorry...by "same database" I meant the same vendor (e.g. test and production should both be Postgres).  Maybe the OP is already doing this, or maybe not.

Comment: @Tim - I want to use the same DB

Comment: @Mark - yes my relation is named 'data_source'

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it appears they are already doing that, so I don't understand what you are suggesting.

Comment: @Mark - yes that's the database

Comment: @Mark - when I make that  change: FATAL: database "public" does not exist. So it refers to DB not schema. And the main/application.properties has same URL